# Como faz um forloop que gere valores aleatórios, depois "appenda" a próxima leva de valores gerados?

Tags: r, for

```
k <- 8
m = 100

for (i in 1:k){
  x <- rnorm(mean = i, 
          sd = .5, 
            n=m)
  y <- rnorm(mean = (8-i),
          sd = .5,
            n=m)
  amostra2 <- data.frame(x,y)
   }
```

Esse é o código que eu tenho. Dado k e m, eu gero valores normalmente distribuídos e os salvo em um data frame. O problema é que desse jeito o loop só reescreve os valores de x e y, quando eu queria "appenda-los", de forma que o comprimento de cada vetor fosse no final k*m (o número de rodadas * a amostra gerada em cada uma).

**ATUALIZAÇÂO**

```
for (i in 1:k){

x <- rnorm(mean = i, 
          sd = .5, 
            n=m)
y <- rnorm(mean = (8-i),
          sd = .5,
            n=m)
assign(paste("amostra_for_",i, sep=""), 
     value = data.frame(x,y)) 
}

for (i in 2:k) {
amostra2 <- rbind(amostra_for_1, 
                paste("amostra_for_",i))
}
```

Agora eu consegui gerar tudo que precisava em k data.frames diferentes, o problema é unir todos os DFs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, eu consegui resolver antes do colega Fernandes responder. Aqui uma solução:

```
datalist = list() ## Util depois para aglutinar os dados

for (i in 1:k){

x <- rnorm(mean = i, 
          sd = .1, 
            n=m)

y <- rnorm(mean = (8-i),
          sd = .1,
            n=m)

datalist[[i]] <- data.frame(x,y)
}

amostra2 <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

Answer (score 5):

Pode-se usar dessa maneira

```
k = 8
m = 100

create_empty_table <- function(num_rows, num_cols) {
  frame <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = num_rows, ncol = num_cols))
  return(frame)
}

amostra = create_empty_table(100, 2*8)

for (i in 1:k){  
  amostra[,(2*i)-1] <- rnorm(mean = i, sd = .5, n=m)
  amostra[,(2*i)] <- rnorm(mean = (8-i), sd = .5, n=m)
}

colnames(amostra) = rep(c('x' ,'y'), 8)
```

Comment: Parece que funciona